# How to use country flags in node and react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am working on https://github.com/hjnilsson/country-flags

basically the instruction said just `npm install --save svg-country-flags`

which i did but I am not sure what how to show the right flag or even the size on the markup or render method in react.

The docs even provided this: http://hjnilsson.github.io/country-flags/

Usually there is some kind of HTML/CSS like `<span className="icon au"></span>` like that but there are no further docs. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The repository provides "all the worlds flags in [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) and [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) format". Meaning it's just a collection of images in convenient formats. It also provided functionality to resize images to specific dimensions if needed.

To use it, install the repo as you specified

```
npm install svg-country-flags --save
```

It will then download the repository and store the SVGs and PNG in `node_modules/svg-country-flags/`

To use it just as it is you could just include a flag using the standard `img` element.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example using svg-country-flags</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <img src="node_modules/svg-country-flags/svg/no.svg" height="50px" width="50px" title="Norwegian flag" />
  </body>
</html>
```

If you need images of a specific size, [read the documentation](https://github.com/hjnilsson/country-flags#user-content-arbitrary-width) as to how to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the [IP2Location™ Country Flags](https://www.ip2location.com/free/country-flags) from IP2Location that contains the flag images of 249 countries around the world as according to ISO3166 standard.

By linking to the ip2location-image-sprite.css, the country flag images can be called easily with the following code:

```
<i class="ip2location-flag-16 flag-au"></i>    //for au flag in 16px
<i class="ip2location-flag-32 flag-us"></i>    //for us flag in 32px
```